# IndexError: index out of range in self

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

`gpt2_fine_tune.py`

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, Trainer, TrainingArguments

# Step 1: Load the pre-trained GPT-2 model
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

# Step 2: Tokenize the training data
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
train_file_path = 'shakespeare.txt'

# Step 3: Prepare the training data
# train_dataset = TextDataset(tokenizer, file_path=train_file_path, block_size=512)
extension = "text"
data_files = train_file_path
raw_datasets = load_dataset(
    extension,
    data_files=data_files,
)
text_column_name = "text"
padding = "max_length"

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=512)


column_names = list(raw_datasets["train"].features)
tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True,
    remove_columns=column_names,
)

# Step 4: Create a TrainingArguments object
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=1000,
    save_steps=5000,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    eval_steps=5000,
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)

# Step 5: Instantiate a Trainer object
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"]
)

# Step 6: Train the model
trainer.train()
```

**Questions:**
What `index` they are talking about?
How do I solve this error?

My error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sarit/study/gpt4all/gpt2_fine_tune.py", line 58, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1662, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1929, in _inner_training_loop
    tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2699, in training_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2731, in compute_loss
    outputs = model(**inputs)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py", line 1075, in forward
    transformer_outputs = self.transformer(
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py", line 842, in forward
    inputs_embeds = self.wte(input_ids)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 162, in forward
    return F.embedding(
  File "/Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2210, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ /Users/sarit/study/gpt4all/gpt2_fine_tune.py:58 in <module>                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│   55 )                                                                                           │
│   56                                                                                             │
│   57 # Step 6: Train the model                                                                   │
│ ❱ 58 trainer.train()                                                                             │
│   59                                                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1662 in train       │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1659 │   │   inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(                                 │
│   1660 │   │   │   self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size  │
│   1661 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│ ❱ 1662 │   │   return inner_training_loop(                                                       │
│   1663 │   │   │   args=args,                                                                    │
│   1664 │   │   │   resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,                                │
│   1665 │   │   │   trial=trial,                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1929 in             │
│ _inner_training_loop                                                                             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1926 │   │   │   │   │   with model.no_sync():                                                 │
│   1927 │   │   │   │   │   │   tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)                  │
│   1928 │   │   │   │   else:                                                                     │
│ ❱ 1929 │   │   │   │   │   tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)                      │
│   1930 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1931 │   │   │   │   if (                                                                      │
│   1932 │   │   │   │   │   args.logging_nan_inf_filter                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2699 in             │
│ training_step                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2696 │   │   │   return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)                    │
│   2697 │   │                                                                                     │
│   2698 │   │   with self.compute_loss_context_manager():                                         │
│ ❱ 2699 │   │   │   loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)                                       │
│   2700 │   │                                                                                     │
│   2701 │   │   if self.args.n_gpu > 1:                                                           │
│   2702 │   │   │   loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training        │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2731 in             │
│ compute_loss                                                                                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2728 │   │   │   labels = inputs.pop("labels")                                                 │
│   2729 │   │   else:                                                                             │
│   2730 │   │   │   labels = None                                                                 │
│ ❱ 2731 │   │   outputs = model(**inputs)                                                         │
│   2732 │   │   # Save past state if it exists                                                    │
│   2733 │   │   # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.                            │
│   2734 │   │   if self.args.past_index >= 0:                                                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in          │
│ _call_impl                                                                                       │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py:1 │
│ 075 in forward                                                                                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1072 │   │   """                                                                               │
│   1073 │   │   return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return  │
│   1074 │   │                                                                                     │
│ ❱ 1075 │   │   transformer_outputs = self.transformer(                                           │
│   1076 │   │   │   input_ids,                                                                    │
│   1077 │   │   │   past_key_values=past_key_values,                                              │
│   1078 │   │   │   attention_mask=attention_mask,                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in          │
│ _call_impl                                                                                       │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py:8 │
│ 42 in forward                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│    839 │   │   head_mask = self.get_head_mask(head_mask, self.config.n_layer)                    │
│    840 │   │                                                                                     │
│    841 │   │   if inputs_embeds is None:                                                         │
│ ❱  842 │   │   │   inputs_embeds = self.wte(input_ids)                                           │
│    843 │   │   position_embeds = self.wpe(position_ids)                                          │
│    844 │   │   hidden_states = inputs_embeds + position_embeds                                   │
│    845                                                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in          │
│ _call_impl                                                                                       │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py:162 in forward   │
│                                                                                                  │
│   159 │   │   │   │   self.weight[self.padding_idx].fill_(0)                                     │
│   160 │                                                                                          │
│   161 │   def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:                                            │
│ ❱ 162 │   │   return F.embedding(                                                                │
│   163 │   │   │   input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,                           │
│   164 │   │   │   self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)                          │
│   165                                                                                            │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/sarit/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2210 in embedding    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2207 │   │   #   torch.embedding_renorm_                                                       │
│   2208 │   │   # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled                                    │
│   2209 │   │   _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)                    │
│ ❱ 2210 │   return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)        │
│   2211                                                                                           │
│   2212                                                                                           │
│   2213 def embedding_bag(                                                                        │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5611#issuecomment-666231984) issue on github, which seems to have an identical problem as you. I'm not sure of the exact details of your situation, but could it be the mentioned problem of exceeding the maximum token limit. Other than that, I'm not really sure how else I can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `dataset`. I found another example and it works.
Here is the complete version. I also shorten the text file to speed up my training time.

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, Trainer, TrainingArguments, TextDataset, \
    DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

# Step 1: Load the pre-trained GPT-2 model
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

# Step 2: Tokenize the training data
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})

# Step 3: Prepare the training data
dataset = TextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="elspeare.txt",
    block_size=128
)
train_size = int(0.9 * len(dataset))
eval_size = len(dataset) - train_size

train_dataset, eval_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, eval_size])

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False
)

print(f"torch.backends.mps.is_available(): {torch.backends.mps.is_available()}")

# Step 4: Create a TrainingArguments object
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=1000,
    save_steps=5000,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    eval_steps=5000,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    use_mps_device=torch.backends.mps.is_available(),
)

# Step 5: Instantiate a Trainer object
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)

# Step 6: Train the model
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model("gpt2_fine_tune")
```